# How to send the message by one Enter Click?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

[Here, When I'm clicking Enter Keyword, it goes to Next Line. Instead of that message have to be sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCP4T.png)

Answer (score -1):

Probably like this:

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("textinput");
var shift = false;
var text;
var lastkey;
window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  if (!evt.shiftKey) {
    shift = false;
  }
  else shift = true;
  lastkey = evt.key.toLowerCase();
}
textarea.oninput = function() {
  if (shift == false) {
    if (!lastkey.includes("enter")) text = this.value;
    else document.getElementById("sendButtonID").click();
  }
  else text = this.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textinput"></textarea>
<button id="sendButtonID" onclick="console.log('Sent: ' + text); textarea.oninput(); textarea.value = ''">Send</button>
```

If you press shift and enter, then it will not send it.